# Does DynamicMethod 'skipVisibility' have a performance penalty?

Tags: c#, cil, emit, dynamicmethod, dynamic-method

When creating a `DynamicMethod` in **C#** for which bypassing visibility is not necessary or irrelevant, what is the best value to specify for the ***skipVisibility*** parameter of the `DynamicMethod` constructor? Is there a performance penalty, i.e., associated with a runtime security demand, for specifying `true` for the ***skipVisibility***, and if so, would the penalty occur on every call, or just once at JIT-time, prior to first access?

MSDN doc: [DynamicMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod?view=netframework-4.7.1)

Comment: Did you try to measure it?

Comment: I will indeed if nobody answers, but I held off because I wouldn't know how to verify what kind of security demands are happening behind the scenes. In other words, it would be hard to try to interpret results when the factor you're supposedly trying to measure is so thoroughly hidden by the runtime/JIT.

Comment: Why should there be a performance penalty for specifying *skipVisibility*? I would think that "skipping" something should yield better performance.

Comment: @IllidanS4 Yes, precisely; I'm asking because this does appear to be a curious case. Since what's being 'skipped' in this case is the enforcement of the (e.g.) `private`, `protected`, or `internal` declarations of a class, I believe that doing so might require that the caller be running at a certain level of elevated security (?), and checking at runtime that this is authorized under the current security evidence would be the penalty, as opposed to simply observing those declarations, which wouldn't need elevation (?).

Answer (score 0):

I found some relevant code in the **.NET** reference source for `DynamicMethod`. As shown below, specifying `skipVisibility` forces a security demand for `ReflectionPermission`. (The code also has another case where this permission is demanded regardless of the `skipVisibility` parameter).

```
[SecurityCritical]
private void PerformSecurityCheck(Type owner, ref StackCrawlMark stackMark, bool skipVisibility)
{
    if (owner == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("owner");

    RuntimeType underlyingSystemType = owner as RuntimeType;
    if (underlyingSystemType == null)
        underlyingSystemType = owner.UnderlyingSystemType as RuntimeType;

    if (underlyingSystemType == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("owner", Environment.GetResourceString("Argument_MustBeRuntimeType"));

    RuntimeType callerType = RuntimeMethodHandle.GetCallerType(ref stackMark);
    if (skipVisibility)
        new ReflectionPermission(ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess).Demand();
    else if (callerType != underlyingSystemType)
        new ReflectionPermission(ReflectionPermissionFlag.MemberAccess).Demand();

    this.m_creatorAssembly = callerType.GetRuntimeAssembly();
    if (underlyingSystemType.Assembly != this.m_creatorAssembly)
        CodeAccessSecurityEngine.ReflectionTargetDemandHelper(PermissionType.SecurityControlEvidence, owner.Assembly.PermissionSet);
}
```

So an answer would be that there may be a performance penalty when specifying **true** for `skipVisibility`. However, depending on the various other argument types you use with `new DynamicMethod(...)` and perhaps the IL that you emit, your `DynamicMethod` may actually *require* `ReflectionPermission`, and you will not be able to specify **false**. The error given in such cases is:

> **System.TypeAccessException**: *Attempt by security transparent method 'DynamicClass.foo(MyType,int)' to access security critical type 'MyType' failed.*